# Sort a str after their int value (Python, JSON)

Tags: python, json, string, sorting, int

First up: Sorry if the title is misleading, I don't know that much about the terminology. :/

A simplified version of my code:

```
import json

y = {}
y['red'] = {'name': "red", 'p': 1}
y['blue'] = {'name': "blue", 'p': 3}
y['green'] = {'name': "green", 'p': 2}

with open('y.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(y, f)

f = open('y.json')
y = json.load(f)


z = '%s%s%s' % (y['red']['name'], " ", y['red']['p'])
zz = '%s%s%s' % (y['blue']['name'], " ", y['blue']['p'])
zzz = '%s%s%s' % (y['green']['name'], " ", y['green']['p'])


print(z)
print(zz)
print(zzz)
```

The output is:

```
red 1
blue 3
green 2
```

Now I want to sort that Output after the value of p. (bigger number, higher in the output. Kind of like the chart in soccer) So I want the output:

```
blue 3
green 2
red 1
```

I want it to be automated, so I don't just want to write

```
print(zz)
print(zzz)
print(z)
```

In my original code, there are also more than just three JSON values, so I don't want any if statements that are super long.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
print(z)
print(zz)
print(zzz)
```

Use:

```
print('\n'.join(sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick comment! If I try that I get: `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. Do I have to do anything else in order for it to work?

Comment: @SkyThaKid Edited it try again

Comment: Oh, nevermid. There was a ) missing in your answer :p. But now it's sorted from 1 to 3, instead of from 3 to 1. Is there a way of reversing it?

Comment: @SkyThaKid Now?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I wanted it to have, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202644/discussion-between-skythakid-and-u10-forward).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the part after `y = json.load(f)` and use the following solution:

```
for dct in sorted(y.values(), key=lambda x: x['p'], reverse=True):
    print(dct['name'], dct['p'])
```

Output:

```
blue 3
green 2
red 1
```